# Javascript: group JSON objects using specific key

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object and wanted to merge them by OrderID, making the items into array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "OrderID":"999123",
    "ItemCode":"TED-072",
    "ItemQuantity":"1",
    "ItemPrice":"74.95",
  },
  {
    "OrderID":"999123",
    "ItemCode":"DY-FBBO",
    "ItemQuantity":"2",
    "ItemName":"DOIY Foosball Bottle Opener > Red",
    "ItemPrice":"34.95",
  }
]
```

and I'm wondering how in Javascript to merge the items on the same order...like this:

```
[{
    "OrderID": "999123",
        "Items": [{
        "ItemCode": "DY-FBBO",
            "ItemQuantity": "2",
            "ItemName": "DOIY Foosball Bottle Opener > Red",
            "ItemPrice": "34.95"
    }, {
        "ItemCode": "TED-072",
            "ItemQuantity": "1",
            "ItemName": "Ted Baker Womens Manicure Set",
            "ItemPrice": "74.95"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: it's rather grouping than merging I would say, no?

Comment: I have tried this and didn't get far:

var result = [];
      
   for (var j = 0; j < dataObj.length; j++) {
    var found = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
     if (result[k].OrderID == dataObj[j].OrderID) {
      found = true;
      result[k].items = result[k].ItemCode.concat(dataObj[j].ItemCode);
      break;
     }
    }
    if (!found) {
     result.push(dataObj[j]);
    }
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want it to do, but it's rather a group function than a merge function :)

You can see the result in the browser console.

```js
var items = [
  {
    "OrderID":"999123",
    "ItemCode":"TED-072",
    "ItemQuantity":"1",
    "ItemPrice":"74.95",
  },
  {
    "OrderID":"999123",
    "ItemCode":"DY-FBBO",
    "ItemQuantity":"2",
    "ItemName":"DOIY Foosball Bottle Opener > Red",
    "ItemPrice":"34.95",
  }
];

function groupBy(ungrouped, groupByProperty) {
  var result = [], 
      getGroup = function (arr, val, groupByProperty) {
        var result, j, jlen;
        for (j = 0, jlen = arr.length; j < jlen; j++) {
          if (arr[j][groupByProperty] === val) {
            result = arr[j];
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!result) {
          result = {};
          result.items = [];
          result[groupByProperty] = val;
          arr.push(result);
        }
        return result;
      }, i, len, item;
  for (i = 0, len = ungrouped.length; i < len; i++) {
    item = getGroup(result, ungrouped[i][groupByProperty], groupByProperty);
    delete ungrouped[i][groupByProperty];
    item.items.push(ungrouped[i]);
  }
  return result;
}

var grouped = groupBy(items, 'OrderID');

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(grouped);
console.log(grouped);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use javascript library like underscorejs/lazyjs/lodash to solve this kind of thing.

Here is the example on using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org):

```
var data = [{
    "OrderID":"999123",
    "ItemCode":"TED-072",
    "ItemQuantity":"1",
    "ItemPrice":"74.95",
}, {
    "OrderID":"999123",
    "ItemCode":"DY-FBBO",
    "ItemQuantity":"2",
    "ItemName":"DOIY Foosball Bottle Opener > Red",
    "ItemPrice":"34.95",
}]

var result = _.chain(data).groupBy(function (e) {
    return e.OrderID;
}).map(function (val, key) {
    return {
        OrderID: key,
        Items: _.map(val, function (eachItem) {
            delete eachItem.OrderID;
            return eachItem;
        })
    };
}).value();
```

Working example:

```js
var data = [{
  "OrderID":"999123",
  "ItemCode":"TED-072",
  "ItemQuantity":"1",
  "ItemPrice":"74.95",
}, {
  "OrderID":"999123",
  "ItemCode":"DY-FBBO",
  "ItemQuantity":"2",
  "ItemName":"DOIY Foosball Bottle Opener > Red",
  "ItemPrice":"34.95",
}];

var result = _.chain(data).groupBy(function (e) {
  return e.OrderID;
}).map(function (val, key) {
  return {
    OrderID: key,
    Items: _.map(val, function (eachItem) {
      delete eachItem.OrderID;
      return eachItem;
    })
  };
}).value();

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I apologize if I didn't put the whole JSON object in my first post. I had problems when the JSON object become this:

var items = [
  {
    "OrderID":"999123",
    "Address":"PH",
    "ItemCode":"TED-072",
    "ItemQuantity":"1",
    "ItemPrice":"74.95",
  },
  {
    "OrderID":"999123",
    "Address":"US",
    "ItemCode":"DY-FBBO",
    "ItemQuantity":"2",
    "ItemName":"DOIY Foosball Bottle Opener > Red",
    "ItemPrice":"34.95",
  }
];

Answer (score 1):

Lodash is a great Javascript Utility library that can help you in this case. Include the latest version of lodash in your code and group the objects like this:

```
var mergedOrders = _.groupBy(OriginalOrders, 'OrderID');
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you'll have to do a function that, for each entry, will check if it match

try this :

```
    // your array is oldArr
var newArr = []
for (var i=0;i<oldArr.length;i++){
    var found = false;
    for(var j=0;j<newArr.length;j++){
        if(oldArr[i]["OrderID"]==newArr[j]["OrderID"]){
            newArr[j]["Items"].push(oldArr[i]);
            found=true;
            break;
    }
    if(!found){
        newArr.push({"OrderID" : oldArr[i]["OrderID"], "Items" : oldArr[i]});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop and create new grouped objects according to your requirement.

For an easier approach I would suggest using [jquery-linq](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

```
var qOrderIds = $.Enumerable.From(myArray).Select(function(item) { return item.OrderID; }).Distinct();
var groupedList = qOrderIds.Select(function(orderId) { 
    return { 
         OrderID: orderId, 
         Items : $.Enumerable.From(myArray).Where(function(item) { item.OrderID === orderId}).ToArray()
    };
}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers.

I was able to attain my goal (maybe a bit dirty and not as beautiful as yours but it worked on my end). Hoping this might help others in the future:

```
function processJsonObj2(dataObj, cfg) {
var retVal = dataObj.reduce(function(x, y, i, array) {

    if (x[cfg.colOrderId] === y[cfg.colOrderId]) {

        var orderId = x[cfg.colOrderId];
        var addressee = x[cfg.colAddressee];
        var company = x[cfg.colCompany];
        var addr1 = x[cfg.colAddress1];
        var addr2 = x[cfg.colAddress2];
        var suburb = x[cfg.colSuburb];
        var state = x[cfg.colState];
        var postcode = x[cfg.colPostcode];
        var country = x[cfg.colCountry];
        var orderMsg = x[cfg.colOrderMessage];
        var carrier = x[cfg.colCarrier];

        delete x[cfg.colOrderId];
        delete y[cfg.colOrderId];
        delete x[cfg.colAddressee];
        delete y[cfg.colAddressee];
        delete x[cfg.colCompany];
        delete y[cfg.colCompany];
        delete x[cfg.colAddress1];
        delete y[cfg.colAddress1];
        delete x[cfg.colAddress2];
        delete y[cfg.colAddress2];
        delete x[cfg.colSuburb];
        delete y[cfg.colSuburb];
        delete x[cfg.colState];
        delete y[cfg.colState];
        delete x[cfg.colPostcode];
        delete y[cfg.colPostcode];
        delete x[cfg.colCountry];
        delete y[cfg.colCountry];
        delete x[cfg.colOrderMessage];
        delete y[cfg.colOrderMessage];
        delete x[cfg.colCarrier];
        delete y[cfg.colCarrier];

        var orderObj = {};
        orderObj[cfg.colOrderId] = orderId;
        orderObj[cfg.colAddressee] = addressee;
        orderObj[cfg.colCompany] = company;
        orderObj[cfg.colAddress1] = addr1;
        orderObj[cfg.colAddress2] = addr2;
        orderObj[cfg.colSuburb] = suburb;
        orderObj[cfg.colState] = state;
        orderObj[cfg.colPostcode] = postcode;
        orderObj[cfg.colCountry] = country;
        orderObj[cfg.colOrderMessage] = orderMsg;
        orderObj[cfg.colCarrier] = carrier;
        orderObj["Items"] = [ x, y ];

        return orderObj;

    } else {
        var orderId = x[cfg.colOrderId];
        var addressee = x[cfg.colAddressee];
        var company = x[cfg.colCompany];
        var addr1 = x[cfg.colAddress1];
        var addr2 = x[cfg.colAddress2];
        var suburb = x[cfg.colSuburb];
        var state = x[cfg.colState];
        var postcode = x[cfg.colPostcode];
        var country = x[cfg.colCountry];
        var orderMsg = x[cfg.colOrderMessage];
        var carrier = x[cfg.colCarrier];

        var itemCode = x[cfg.colItemCode];
        var itemQuantity = x[cfg.colItemQuantity];
        var itemName = x[cfg.colItemName];
        var itemPrice = x[cfg.colitemPrice];

        var item = {};
        item[cfg.colItemCode] = itemCode;
        item[cfg.colItemQuantity] = itemQuantity;
        item[cfg.colItemName] = itemName;
        item[cfg.colItemPrice] = itemPrice;

        var orderObj = {};
        orderObj[cfg.colOrderId] = orderId;
        orderObj[cfg.colAddressee] = addressee;
        orderObj[cfg.colCompany] = company;
        orderObj[cfg.colAddress1] = addr1;
        orderObj[cfg.colAddress2] = addr2;
        orderObj[cfg.colSuburb] = suburb;
        orderObj[cfg.colState] = state;
        orderObj[cfg.colPostcode] = postcode;
        orderObj[cfg.colCountry] = country;
        orderObj[cfg.colOrderMessage] = orderMsg;
        orderObj[cfg.colCarrier] = carrier;
        orderObj["Items"] = [ item ];

        return orderObj;
    }

});

return retVal;
```

}